# Ascending sorting, starting from 2nd or 3rd ID and back..for lack of better description

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is probably a simple one, but I can't wrap my head around it...everything I researched mentionned ascending or descending sorting of an array...
I have an array ['id', 'things'].

Foreach ($things as $thing) loop echoes it in this order:
1,2,3,4 (obvious)
How can I sort it like so:
2,3,4,1
and then
3,4,1,2
and maybe
4,1,2,3
...
Simply in ascending order, but starting from a different Id each time...
And the actual IDs in the table are not necessarily 1,2,3,4 they can be 5,6,7,8 (always in a groupe though)

Is this very obvious? I am still on the lowest rungs of the PHP scale :)

Comment: you might want to use usort() see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 1):

You can implement some custom iterator. Something like :

```
class ArrayOffsetIterator implements Iterator {
    private $_array;
    private $_index;
    private $_startIndex;

    public function __construct(array $arr, $startIndex = 0) {
        if ($startIndex < 0) throw new Exception("Start index must be greater than zero");

        $this->_array = (array) $arr;

        if (empty($this->_array)) {
            $this->_index = $this->_startIndex = 0;
        } else {
            $this->_index = $this->_startIndex = $startIndex % count($arr);
        }
    }

    public function current() {
        if (empty($this->_array)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $this->_array[$this->key()];
        }
    }

    public function key() {
        if (empty($this->_array)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $this->_index % count($this->_array);
        }
    }

    public function next() {
        if (!$this->valid()) throw new Exception("End of iterator");
        $this->_index++;
        return $this->current();
    }

    public function rewind() {
        $this->_index = $this->_startIndex;
    }

    public function valid() {
        $size = count($this->_array);
        if ($size == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $count = ($this->_index % $size) + (((int) ($this->_index / $size)) * $size) - $this->_startIndex;
            return $count < $size;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it this way :

```
// some unsorted array
$array = array(
    'Erik',
    'Carl',
    'Alphred',
    'Doris',
    'Bob',
);

// sort it however you like...
sort($array);

// create your iterator (we'll start at index 2 of 0 based index)
$iterator = new ArrayOffsetIterator($array, 2);

// because it's an iterator, we can use it in foreach directly
foreach ($iterator as $key => $item) {
   echo $key . ' => ' . $item . "\n";
}
```

WIll output

```
2 => Carl
3 => Doris
4 => Erik
0 => Alphred
1 => Bob
```

Comment: Holy moly this is more complicated than I thought! I will try to make sense of it all and get back here.

Comment: @user1924460, but reusable, and pluggable. :) And it's not *as* complicated as you think... it's a simple iterator. It looks this way because I chose to implement [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) to make it compliant with a conventional iterator. The most complicate method is `valid` and it merely simple arithmetic where `$count` holds the number of times we called `next`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using `array_merge` and `array_slice`, like this:

```
$myArray = array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3);

function customSort ($array, $start = 7)
{
    sort($array);
    return array_merge(array_slice($array, $start - 1), array_slice($array, 0, $start - 1));
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(customSort($myArray));
```

Comment: If you set `$start` to a small value (like `1`), it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think the description is not that clear, at some point it gives the impression the it is about permutations.. anyway if I have understood it correctly and it is true that your numbers are sequential maybe this could be of some help:

```
function test($min, $max, $start){
    if( $start === $min)
        return range($min,$max);
    return array_merge(range($start,$max), range($min,$start-1));
}
```

I like the answer of blausocke too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, you all pointed me in some good directions.
I found a very simple solution that works for me and is scalable:
My $firstarray was ascending 1,2,3,4, this one stays like that.

On the second array:
I used array_shift($myarray); to remove the first value from the array and store it as $first_value,
then I used 
array_push($myarray, $first_value); to insert the first value at the end of the array.
$myarray now = 2,3,4,1 = $secondarray

For the $thirdarray, I used $secondarray and did to it the same thing as the 2nd one.
So $thirdarray = 3,4,1,2

It's kind of crude, but works for my purpose and is only 6 lines or so!
Thank you all....

Comment: This is basically the same idea is I posed.